# Remove numpy concat from algo

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function called gen_data which will make a single pass through a list and construct a 3D array. I then iterate across a list of list, applying the function gen_data, and then concat the results together.

```
fst = lambda x: x[0]
snd = lambda x: x[1]

def gen_data(data,p=0, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, n_session = N_SESSION, 
    x = np.zeros((batch_size,SEQ_LENGTH,vocab_size))
    y = np.zeros(batch_size)

    for n in range(batch_size):
        ptr = n
        for i in range(SEQ_LENGTH):
            x[n,i,char_to_ix[data[p+ptr+i]]] = 1.
        if(return_target):
            y[n] = char_to_ix[data[p+ptr+SEQ_LENGTH]]
    return x, np.array(y,dtype='int32')

def batch_data(data):
    nest = [gen_data(datum) for datum in data]
    x = np.concatenate(map(fst,nest))
    y = np.concatenate(map(snd,nest))
    return (x,y)
```

What is the best way to combine these functions so I do not need to make multiple passes back through the data to concatenate the results?

To clarify, the goal would be remove the need to zip/concat/splat/list comp in general. To be able to initialize the x tensor to the correct dimensions and then iterate across each datum/SEQ_LENGTH, batch_size in a single pass.

Comment: Do you mean something like `x,y = zip(*nest)`?

Comment: To clarify, the goal would be remove the need to zip/concat/splat/list comp in general. To be able to initialize the x tensor to the correct dimensions and then iterate across each datum/SEQ_LENGTH, batch_size in a single pass.

Comment: You could pass views of global arrays to `gen_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing things, here are a few quick fixes:

```
def gen_data(data,p=0, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, n_session = N_SESSION, 
    x = np.zeros((batch_size,SEQ_LENGTH,vocab_size))
    y = np.zeros(batch_size, dtype=int)   # initial to desired type

    for n in range(batch_size):
        ptr = n
        for i in range(SEQ_LENGTH):
            x[n,i,char_to_ix[data[p+ptr+i]]] = 1.
        if(return_target):
            y[n] = char_to_ix[data[p+ptr+SEQ_LENGTH]]
    return x, y 
    # y is already an array; don't need this: np.array(y,dtype='int32')
```

`nest = [gen_data(datum) for datum in data]` produces, I think,

`[(x0,y0), (x1,y1),...]` where `x` is 3d (n,m,y), and `y` is 1d (n)

`x = np.concatenate([n[0] for n in nest])`  (I like this format over mapping) look ok to me.  Compared to all the list comprehension operations, `concatenate` is relatively cheap.  Look at the guts of `np.vstack`, etc to see how those use comprehensions along with concatenate.

A small example:

```
In [515]: def gen():
    return np.arange(8).reshape(2,4),np.arange(1,3)
   .....: 

In [516]: gen()
Out[516]: 
(array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]), array([1, 2]))

In [517]: nest=[gen() for _ in range(3)]

In [518]: nest
Out[518]: 
[(array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]), array([1, 2])),
 (array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]), array([1, 2])),
 (array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]), array([1, 2]))]

In [519]: np.concatenate([x[0] for x in nest])
Out[519]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

In [520]: np.concatenate([x[1] for x in nest])
Out[520]: array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

`zip*` effectively does a 'tanspose' on a nested list, so the arrays could be constructed with:

```
In [532]: nest1=zip(*nest)

In [533]: np.concatenate(nest1[0])
Out[533]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

In [534]: np.concatenate(nest1[1])
Out[534]: array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

Still requires concatenates.

Since `nest` is a list of tuples, it could serve as input to a structured array:

```
In [524]: arr=np.array(nest,dtype=[('x','(2,4)int'),('y','(2,)int')])

In [525]: arr['x']
Out[525]: 
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6, 7]]])

In [526]: arr['y']
Out[526]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

Another possibility is to initial `x` and `y`, and iterate.  But you are already doing this in `gen_data`.  Only thing new is that I'd be assigning larger blocks.

```
x = ...
y = ...
for i in range(...):
    x[i,...], y[i] = gen(data[i])
```

I like the comprehension solutions better, but I won't speculate on speeds.

In terms of speed I think it's the low level iteration in `gen_data` that is the time consumer.  Concatenating larger blocks is relatively fast.

---

Another idea - since you are iterating over the rows of arrays within `gen_data`, how about passing views to that function, and iterate over those.

```
def gen_data(data,x=None,y=None):
    # accept array or make own
    if x is None:
        x = np.zeros((3,4),int)
    if y is None:
        y = np.zeros(3,int)
    for n in range(3):
        x[n,...] = np.arange(4)+n
        y[n] = n
    return x,y
```

with no inputs, generate arrays as before:

```
In [543]: gen_data(None)
Out[543]: 
(array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]]),
 array([0, 1, 2]))
```

or initial a pair, and iterate over views:

```
In [544]: x,y = np.zeros((9,4),int),np.zeros(9,int)

In [546]: for i in range(0,9,3):
   .....:     gen_data(None,x[i:i+3,...],y[i:i+3])

In [547]: x
Out[547]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5]])
In [548]: y
Out[548]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the list comp/concat in general and initialize x to np.zeros(batch_size * len(data)) ?

Comment: Assuming `gen_data` has to produce this tuple of arrays, I don't off hand see another  way of repackaging the resulting list of tuples.

Comment: I've outlined an alternative in which `gen_data` assigns values directly to views of global arrays.